# C# change the first 32bit Int of a GUID

Tags: c#, guid

I have a `GUID` which I created with `GUID.NewGUID()`. Now I want to replace the first 32 bit of it with a specific 32-bit Integer while keeping the rest as they are.
Is there a function to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ToByteArray()` function and then the Guid constructor.

```
byte[] buffer = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
buffer[0] = 0;
buffer[1] = 0;
buffer[2] = 0;
buffer[3] = 0;

Guid guid = new Guid(buffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `Guid` struct has a constructor that takes a byte array and can return its current bytes, it's actually quite easy:

```
//Create a random, new guid
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
Console.WriteLine(guid);

//The original bytes
byte[] guidBytes = guid.ToByteArray();
//Your custom bytes
byte[] first4Bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt32) 0815);

//Overwrite the first 4 Bytes
Array.Copy(first4Bytes, guidBytes, 4);

//Create new guid based on current values
Guid guid2 = new Guid(guidBytes);
Console.WriteLine(guid2);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/lpMsUa)

---

Keep in mind however, that the order of bytes returned from `BitConverter` depends on your processor architecture (`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`) and that your Guid's entropy decreases by 2<sup>32</sup> if you use the same number every time (which, depending on your application might not be as bad as it sounds, since you have 2<sup>128</sup> to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

The question is about replacing bits, but if someone wants to replace first characters of guid directly, this can be done by converting it to string, replacing characters in string and converting back. Note that replaced characters should be valid in hex, i.e. numbers 0 - 9 or letters a - f.

```
var uniqueGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
var uniqueGuidStr = "1234" + uniqueGuid.ToString().Substring(4);
var modifiedUniqueGuid = Guid.Parse(uniqueGuidStr);
```